# How to add annotations to UIImageview iPhone programming

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, uiimageview, annotations

I am trying to solve this but don't know where to start. I have a image of a map of let's say a mall loaded into a uiimageview and would like to add annotations over the imagview not over a map view. How would this be achieved? Any help with this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the correct approach for doing the annotation in UIImageview. You can do by drawing lines between two points and implementing the touch methods.

More detail can be find on this link [click here](http://iosbucket.blogspot.in/2016/01/annotating-uiimage-drawing-and-writing.html).There is also a sample project that you can use.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgCorrection.frame.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        imgCorrection.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgCorrection.frame.size.width, height: imgCorrection.frame.size.height))
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y)
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, pointerWidth)
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 254.0/255.0 , 87.0/255.0,86.0/255.0, 1.0)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
        imgCorrection.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved easily if you draw analogy from the `MKMapView`.

In `mapView` annotation are added to a particular `coordinate(lat,long)` and they know about their position so whenever we zoom or pan the map they remains at the same location. In your case you will need to use `CGPoint(x,y)` to track annotation's location on `imageview`.

Two points we need to consider from the analogy:

1. If we zoom-in/zoom-out our `imageMap` than the point(x,y) for the annotation should be scaled/calculated properly.**(For Zooming)**
2. The annotations must be added on the `imageMap` so than if we Pan the `imageMap` the annotations move along with the map, but remains at their position.**(For Panning)**

Also to provide zoom and panning functionality you will need to use `UIScrollView` as `superview` of `imageMap`. You will need to handle delegate methods for this.

You can use imageView/label/button/custom view  or any other view for showing annotation and other annotation operations.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can add **UILabels** as subviews to your UIImageView.